# Check if value exists in a dictionary of dictionaries and get the key(s)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
x = {'NIFTY': {11382018: 'NIFTY19SEPFUT', 13177346: 'NIFTY19OCTFUT', 12335874: 'NIFTY19NOVFUT'}}
```

The dictionary has a lot of other dictionaries inside.

I want to check whether example:

```
y = 11382018
```

exists in the dictionary, if yes, get the master `key` in this case `NIFTY` and the value of the above `key` i.e. `'NIFTY19SEPFUT'`

I can do this in the following way I assume:

```
for key in x.keys():
    di = x[key]
    if y in di.keys():
       inst = key
       cont = di[y]
```

Just wondering if there is a better way.

I was thinking along the lines of not having to loop over the entire dictionary master `keys`

Comment: only 2 levels of nesting?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes only two levels

Comment: How would you handle multiple matches? If these can't happen, I'd pick a datastructure where that can not happen, if possible. Doing so would then also change your question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt multiple matches cannot happen. Trying to figure out how that would change the question. I get the data in the format above, Which structure would you change it to?

Answer (score 2):

A more compact way to retrieve both values of interest would be using a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
[(k, sv) for k,v in x.items() for sk,sv in v.items() if sk == y]
# [('NIFTY', 'NIFTY19SEPFUT')]
```

Answer (score 2):

More compact version (generic):

```
[(k, v[y]) for k, v in d.items() if y in v]
```

Or:

```
*next(((k, v[y]) for k, v in d.items() if y in v), 'not found')
```

if you can guarantee the key is found only in one nested dictionary. (Note that I have used `d` as dictionary here, simply because that feels more meaningful)

**Code**:

```
d = {'NIFTY': {11382018: 'NIFTY19SEPFUT', 13177346: 'NIFTY19OCTFUT', 12335874: 'NIFTY19NOVFUT'}}

y = 11382018
print([(k, v[y]) for k, v in d.items() if y in v])

# or:
# print(*next(((k, v[y]) for k, v in d.items() if y in v), 'not found'))
```

Comment: next is a nice idea here, though you might want to add a default value

Answer (score 1):

Straightforwardly (for only 2 levels of nesting):

```
x = {'NIFTY': {11382018: 'NIFTY19SEPFUT', 13177346: 'NIFTY19OCTFUT', 12335874: 'NIFTY19NOVFUT'}}
search_key = 11382018
parent_key, value = None, None

for k, inner_d in x.items():
    if search_key in inner_d:
        parent_key, value = k, inner_d[search_key]
        break

print(parent_key, value)   # NIFTY NIFTY19SEPFUT
```